# Is CryptoNote.org dead?

Tags: cryptonote

The CryptoNote.org website doesn't seem to have been updated since 2015. Their support forum is broken (I don't receive confirmation emails allowing me to register) and their twitter account has not been updated in a while. I know that Monero is based on CryptoNote which implies CryptoNote is not dead but why hasn't the CryptoNote.org website been updated or forum working?

Comment: Monero being based on CryptoNote does not imply CryptoNote not being dead. Windows is based on MS-DOS, and MS-DOS is dead.

Comment: @user36303 so is it dead?

Comment: I don't know, so I posted a comment and not an anwer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst Monero is based on CryptoNote, the codebase and feature-set is now very different.

The CryptoNote website *and* code repository has not been updated in a long time.

So whilst the website and code has not been updated, for historical purposes, I guess it's nice they are still online, even though not maintained.

Arguably the most active development on privacy focused, decentralized and fungible digital money is happening on Monero, with a wealth of information updated regularly on multiple channels.

Comment: There is no official Monero forking guide I know of. And forking based on the guide at CryptoNote is so outdated it probably has little value and won't work for forking Monero as the projects are so different now.

Comment: you were right when you said the CryptoNote guide is outdated for example, the Seed Nodes IP Addresses. Have created a new post for this now. https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8633/monero-forking-guide

Comment: The CryptoNote Forking Guide does still provide a head start and the tools provided do still work, although the guide doesn't provide a means to determine a unique value for the daemon Network identifier. https://cryptonotestarter.org/inner.html

Comment: @BarryW.Black Monero is almost unrecognizable from the original CryptoNote code, features and functionality. The question does not ask about forking or cloning. Please stay on-topic.